# Read/print socket ouput while waiting on cin (w/o multithreading)

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, tcp

i have a client program that connects to a server via a TCP socket, below:

```
int main ( )
{
    std::cout << "HunterChat client starting up" << std::endl;
    std::string cmd;
    std::string reply;
    bool cont = true;
    ClientSocket client_socket ( "localhost", PORT );
    try {   
        while(cont) {
                try {
                    std::cout << ">> ";
                    // std::getline(std::cin,cmd);
                    gets(cmd);
                    if(cmd.compare("logout") == 0) {
                        cont = false;
                        break;
                    }
                    client_socket << cmd;
                    client_socket >> reply;
                    std::cout << reply << std::endl;
                }
                catch ( SocketException& e) {
                    std::cout << "Exception was caught:" << e.description() << "\n";
                }
        }
    }
    catch ( SocketException& e ) {
        std::cout << "Exception was caught:" << e.description() << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

ClientSocket is a custom class that lets me set up and use the TCP connection; the stream operator is overloaded with, the following code:

```
int status = ::send ( m_sock, s.c_str(), s.size(), MSG_NOSIGNAL );
if ( status == -1 )
{
    return false;
}
else
{
    return true;
}
```

The TCP connection itself is working fine, so I won't clutter the post up with more of it. The problem is that one of the available commands involves sending input to a client instance while said client is still waiting for cin input. This means that the server messages only get read and written when I type something into cin. I'm trying to avoid using multithreading, so is there any way to allow cin to be interrupted without it?

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use a loop and the function `kbhit()` to check for user input if you really want to. However, threading seems to me such a better solution.

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;



int main()
{
    while(1)
    {
        if(kbhit())
        {
            char x = getch();
            // ...
        }
        // check messages asynchronously here
    }
}
```